# Convert a .docx document as a pdf document and attach to an email

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, buffer, docx, wordtopdf

I am currently running a cloud function to generate a .docx document and then deliver it to a user using nodemailer. Here is the code to generate the .docx file using docxtemplater:

```
  const file_name = 'template.docx';// this is the file saved in my firebase storage
  const templateRef = await admin.storage().bucket()
      .file(file_name);
  const template_content = (await templateRef.download())[0];
  const zip = new PizZip(template_content);

  let doc;
  try {
    doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, { linebreaks: true });
  } catch (error) {
    // Catch compilation errors (errors caused by the compilation of the template : misplaced tags)
    errorHandler(error);
  }

  doc.setData({
    name: data.name
  });

  try {
    doc.render();
  } catch (error) {
    errorHandler(error);
  }

  const contentBuffer = doc.getZip().generate({ type: "nodebuffer" });
```

What I am trying to achieve now is to change that contentBuffer into a pdf file that can then be attached to an email. I tried using PDF make but it generated a blank pdf. Is there a way this can be done using any of the pdf Generators?

Comment: What is the error? Why a zip is required to work with docx and pdf? Share a reproducible code in github

Answer (score 1):

From a quick search I've found this info in the [Docxtemplater's docs](https://docxtemplater.com/docs/faq/#convert-to-pdf):

> ##### Convert to PDF
>
> It is not possible to convert docx to PDF with docxtemplater, ... There are many tools to do this conversion.
>
> The first one is to use `libreoffice headless`, which permits you to generate a PDF from a docx document:
>
> You just have to run:
>
> ```
> libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir . input.docx
> ```
>
> This will convert the input.docx file into input.pdf file.

This also lists `PDFtron` and `Aspose` as another options if the results of the first one aren't good enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

From cloud function, it's not possible to call LibreOffice. So I recommend you to use alternative to docxtemplater which include pdf generation. You can for example use [Carbone](https://carbone.io)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a docker container that exposes an api for the conversion of docx to pdf, I can recommend [Gotenberg](https://gotenberg.dev). Of course, under the hood it is using similiar libraries which [@Ido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74837528/15541102) mentioned.